# Add class to parent div if child classes are present

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code:

```
<div class="uk-dropdown uk-dropdown-navbar">
    <div class="sclogin sourcecoast">        
    </div>
</div>
```

and I want to use jQuery to add a class called `large` to the parent div if `sclogin` and `sourcecoast` classes are present in the child div. So the result would be:

```
<div class="uk-dropdown uk-dropdown-navbar large">
    <div class="sclogin sourcecoast">        
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this :

```
$('.sclogin.sourcecoast').parent().addClass('large');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$('.uk-dropdown-navbar').has('.sclogin.sourcecoast').addClass('large')
```